# Very slow jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, animation, scrolltop

I'm building a vertical ticker for a website. I've made a div of which I animate the scrollTop with jQuery. In between the scrolling I'd like to have a really slow animation downwards. The problem is that the slow animation doesn't go smoothly. So see it jump to every pixel.

Here is the demo: http://test.raapwerk.nl/popma/

Is there a way of making the slow animation in between run smoothly?

Thanks!

Comment: `var speed = 8000` increase the speed?

Comment: _"see it jump to every pixel"_ - But pixels are the smallest unit available to you, so what else could it do? It would be less jarring if you made it _really_ slow, but you'd still see each step.

Comment: Wow. Two downvotes.. Must've been a stupid question? ;) Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Don't take the down-votes to heart -  if it was a stupid question it'd have eight down-votes and be closed by now. Hang around Stack Overflow for a while and you'll see correct and thorough answers downvoted even after they're accepted. I think it would be better if the system forced at least the first down-voter to leave a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your duration is set so high that there are not enough pixels available for a smooth animation. If you set a duration of `8 seconds` for `20px` you can compare it to `~3fps`.

So the only way to get this smoother is to **decrease your duration or increase your pixel distance**.

I've made a small jsfiddle to demonstrate that: [**PROBLEM DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/seXQR/3/)

Comment: Yeah thought so too. Just checking. Thanks!